# How would this circuit behave?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current

[image]

A function generator is hooked up to two resistors in series.

The voltage across the function generator changes over time, shown by the different graphs

The questions ask to find the output voltage at points w,x,y,z with respect to the ground.

I'm confused about the behavior of circuit, since it is not a closed loop, but it is grounded. I have not dealt with these before. All I need is a nudge in the right direction so I can figure out what exactly is going on here.

Comment: 1. Why do you say it's "not a closed loop"? There are conductive paths from a to b to c to d back to a. That's a closed loop. 2. What node do you consider to be the output?

Comment: Im not sure about the path connecting d to the ground, how does this change the behavior?

Comment: This seems to be a problem better suited for Electrical Engineering SE, you may want to move your question there.

Comment: ok ill try that

Comment: $w$, $y$, $x$ and $z$ are not in the basic circuit.

Comment: @Doldrums, since there's only one ground symbol in the circuit, it has no effect (By KCL, no current can flow in or out of whatever physical ground is attached to it). It just tells you which node you should use as the reference for measuring voltage at other nodes.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has already been reposted on EE.

Comment: I moved it to EE like Charlie suggested